# Error correction : I have been informed that Dr. Sinha visits London the following month

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, present-simple, future-time

> I have been informed that **Dr. Sinha visits London the following month.**

I came across this sentence in a error correction exercise related to articles. Although there are no errors related to articles in it but is the tense of bold part correct ? Shouldn't it be *Dr. Sinha will visit London the following month* ? Or *Dr. Sinha will be visiting London the following month ?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sense that a future is valid here is correct, although the sentence could also refer to the past, since **the following month** can refer to any following month, future or past.  If you want to refer to the month after the present month, it is **next month** (without article).  *Dr Sinha will visit London next month*.

There are several choices for the future:

will visit

will be visiting

is to visit

There are several choices for the past:

visited

was visiting

was to visit

> I hear you intend to visit London next spring.
>   -- Yes, that is true.
>   When do you arrive?
>   -- In April.
>   Do you intend to visit the British Library right away?
>   -- No, actually. I hope to visit it the following month, in May.
>
> I heard you visited London last spring.
>   -- Yes, that is true.
>   When did you arrive?
>   -- In April.
>   Did you visit the British Library right away?
>   -- No, actually. I visited it the following month, in May.

P.S. And it is also possible to use simple present (e.g. **visits**) to refer to something which will happen in the future, especially when talking about an itinerary or a plan. Let's assume the speaker is speaking on June 1st:

> We **arrive** in London on June 22nd. <sup>simple present referring to something on a schedule or calendar</sup>

Thus, if you are telling someone about Dr Sinha's travel schedule in the upcoming months, you could say:

> Dr. Sinha **visits** London in late June, and the month after, he **goes** on to Paris. He will not return until August. You could make an appointment to see him during that month.